# How to make only one server runs job in cluster mode

Tags: java, plsql

I am beginner to web development,in my project people gave me R&D task and the task is 
  I am deploying same war in two servers and running the servers in cluster mode, in the code they have schedule some jobs, As there are two servers these jobs are running on two servers and results in the duplication of data in DB(as two servers are running same jobs independently),please any one help me how to solve this situation.